# How to solve the equation of motion of the minimal surface for spherical subsystems in AdS?

Tags: entropy, ads-cft, holographic-principle

In order to compute the holographic entanglement entropy for a spherical subsystem in AdS using the [Ryu-Takayanagi conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0605073), one needs to solve the following second order nonlinear differential equation:

$$zr(z)r''(z) - (d-1)r(z)(r'(z))^3 - (d-2)z(r'(z))^2 - (d-1)r(z)r'(z) - (d-2)z = 0$$

and obtain the solution $r^2 + z^2 = l^2$, I need help in obtaining this solution.

N.B.: The equation (in a mildly different form), and its solution are given in [hep-th/0605073](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0605073)

Comment: @SabyasachiMaulik See my post on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198202/

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a disk $d=2$, the equation is simplified:
$$zr(z)r''(z) - r(z)(r'(z))^3  - r(z)r'(z)  = 0$$
We discard the obvious solution of the equation $r = 0$, then putting $r' = y$ we find
$$zy'=y^3+y$$
This equation is easily integrated, and using the boundary condition $y(R) =\infty $, we find
$$\frac {r'}{\sqrt {1+r'^2}}=\frac {z}{R}$$

Solving the equation for $r`$, we have
$$r'=\pm \frac {z}{\sqrt {R^2-z^2}}$$
And find finally
$$r=\pm \sqrt {R^2-z^2}$$
Note that in the article [Aspects of Holographic Entanglement Entropy](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0605073)
the authors cited another equation on p.34
$$ rzz′′ + (d−1)z(z′)^3 + (d−1)zz′ + dr(z′)^2 + dr = 0.
$$
For this equation, the solution $z^2+r^2=R^2$ exists for any $d$.

Comment: Thank you, any suggestion on how to generalize to higher dimensions?

Comment: @SabyasachiMaulik See update to my answer

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: @SabyasachiMaulik Use code `r*z*z'' + (d \[Minus] 1) z (z')^3 + (d \[Minus] 1) z*z' + d*r (z')^2 + d*r /. {z -> Sqrt[R^2 - r^2], z' -> -(r/Sqrt[-r^2 + R^2]), 
   z'' -> -(r^2/(-r^2 + R^2)^(3/2)) - 1/Sqrt[-r^2 + R^2]} // Simplify`